# Email permission

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get user email from facebook account.

http://instanceof.ru/scr/2012/09/26/26.09.2012-22.05.01.png - this is permissions settings

```
    require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        //echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
        $user = null;
    }

}

var_dump($user_profile);exit;
```

But there is no email in output

What I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried getting it using `$facebook-api('/me?fields=email)` and check if it returns a value

Answer (score 1):

Getting a user's email requires that permission from the user in the authorization.  Try something like the following in your authorization:

```
if (!$fbUser) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => 'email',
                'redirect_uri' => 'YOUR REDIRECT URL GOES HERE'
            )
        );
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }
```